# Error while converting certificare : openssl unrecognized flag?

Tags: openssl, x509, flags

I'm receiving this error:

```
~ > openssl x509 -in cert.pem -out cert.crt
x509: Unrecognized flag in cert.pem
x509: Use -help for summary.
```

Can someone help me how can I proceed with this? I have tried to search but no answer found.

I have tried with

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in yourPemFilename.pem -out certfileOutName.crt
```

but no luck.